# Linq tables do not appear on list for datasources for BindingSources

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using linq to sql to populate a datagridview. I can't set the grid's corresponding BindingSource's datasource property to my linq datatable at design time, the only options are "Project Datasources". I have to manually edit the bindingsource's datasource in the InitializeComponent sub of the form as below, then it appears as the value of the DataSource property for the BindingSource on the form designer (but still not in the list). What gives here?
Here is the line of code I have to add in InitializeComponent sub:

```
Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = GetType(ProjectNamespace.MyLinqTableClass)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in Help files: How to: Create LINQ to SQL Classes Mapped to Tables and Views (O/R Designer) it appears this is the steps you take: generate the dbml file -> create a Data Source based on the linq table, then that DataSource appears in the forms design view and you are able to set bindingsources's datasource propery to it, I was trying to set it directly to the linq table, but guess you have to set it to the DataSource based on the linq table.